# Converting numeric values of multiple columns to factor levels that are consecutive integers in (descending) order

Tags: r

Consider the data frame `c` containing numeric values:

```
a = c(0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 0, 1, 3, 6)
b = c(2, 2, 4, 6, 7, 1, 1, 3, 7)
c = data.frame(var1 = a, var2 = b)
```

I would like to convert every column to factor levels as follows (it's important that the lowest level is 1 and not 0):

```
levels(c$var1) = length(unique(c$var1)):1
levels(c$var2) = length(unique(c$var2)):1
```

The number of columns for which I have to do this can vary so I'd like to further automate this. I can do this with a loop but is there a way of doing this for  without a loop? I don't see how I can do this with `apply`, `lapply` or even `catcolwise` (from `plyr`) because of the function `length(unique())` is each time applied to a different column.

Comment: What do you want to happen to the `0`'s in `var1`? And in `levels(c$var1) = length(unique(c$var1)):1` the value `6` is not being represented in the levels, is that what you wanted?

Comment: @emilliman5, what @akrun his solution provides is what I want (so `0` to `1` and `6` to `5` for `var1`). It's for something related to computing an ordinal power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the columns and assign the `levels` as the reverse sequence of `length` of `unique` elements in the column and assign the output back to the dataset

```
c[] <-lapply(c, function(x) {levels(x) <- length(unique(x)):1; x})
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, that does the trick. I hadn't realized that I can define a customized function that can assign the desired values to the levels.

Comment: @koteletje  Yes, you can do with anonymous function call