# Converting numeric values to factor levels with factor levels assigned on the basis of the numeric ordering

Tags: r

Consider the data frame

```
a = c(0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 0, 1, 3, 6, 12)
b = c(letters[5:9], letters[2:6])
c = data.frame(var1 = a, var2 = b)
```

I want to convert all values in the data frame to consecutive integers factor levels starting from `1` and use these as numeric values to compute something (in reality I don't do this for the letters but I just added these to explain my problem ;) ).

With some help ([Converting numeric values of multiple columns to factor levels that are consecutive integers in (descending) order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488362/converting-numeric-values-of-multiple-columns-to-factor-levels-that-are-consecut)), I did this through:

```
c[] = lapply(c, function(x) {levels(x) <- 1:length(unique(x)); x})
```

Unfortunately, this only replaces the values with their respective factor levels for the `character` column `var2` but not the for the `numeric` column `var1` (notice the `0` in column `var1`)

```
> c
   var1 var2
1     0    4
2     1    5
3     3    6
4     5    7
...
```

To alleviate the problem I converted all columns to character when creating `c`

```
c = as.data.frame(sapply(data.frame(var1 = a, var2 = b), as.character))
```

This yields

```
   var1 var2
1     1    4
2     2    5
3     4    6
4     5    7
5     6    8
6     1    1
7     2    2
8     4    3
9     6    4
10    3    5
```

The problem here, however, is that the value `12` (`c[10,'var1']`) in column `var1` is considered as the 3rd value (it gets assigned factor level `3` after levels `1` and `2` for values `0` and `1`) rather than the last value (factor level `6` because it is the largest numeric value in `var1`).

Is there a way to assign factor levels on the basis of the numeric ordering at the same time replacing the numeric values by their factor levels?

Comment: I just found a way by adding zeroes to 1 digit numbers through `c   = data.frame(var1 = str_pad(a, 2, pad = "0"), var2 = b)`. Are there any cleaner solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description, it seems like the OP wanted to change the `levels` to numeric values starting from 1.  This can be done using `match`

```
c[] <- lapply(c, function(x) factor(match(x, sort(unique(x)))))
c
#    var1 var2
#1     1    4
#2     2    5
#3     3    6
#4     4    7
#5     5    8
#6     1    1
#7     2    2
#8     3    3
#9     5    4
#10    6    5
```

#### data

```
a <- c(0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 0, 1, 3, 6, 12)
b <- c(letters[5:9], letters[2:6])
c <- data.frame(var1 = a, var2 = b)
```

---

Based on the code in the comments, another option to replace `str_pad` is

```
c <- data.frame(var1 = sprintf("%02d", a), var2=b, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```